# simple alternative to ext2fsd?

Tags: software-recommendation, ext4

I have been using ext2fsd on a few occasions to print ext4 ubuntu files from Windows 7.  I found the program to be somewhat unpolished with respect to simplicity, intuitiveness and the user interface.  Perhaps I'm just not willing to spend much time looking at it and learning about it.  Is there a simpler alternative?

Edit: The blog for ext2read is pleading for developers so that makes it a little less attractive as an alternative.

Comment: Have you tried using `ext2fsd` in xp or Vista compatibility mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though ext2fsd is more widely used tool for your purpose, but if you are really not comfortable with GUI it provides and learning curve associated with it, here is one alternative which meets your criteria though not as powerful as ext2fsd: Ext2Read

**Ext2Read is an explorer like utility to explore ext2/ext3/ext4 files. It now supports LVM2 and EXT4 extents. It can be used to view and copy files and folders. It can recursively copy entire folders. It can also be used to view and copy disk and file**

Link to project:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2read/

Comment: Thanks. I did see ext2read but they are pleading for developers.  As for ext2fsd, it fails on the first installation because of the need for "elevation" which I think means admin rights. That didn't make sense since I am the admin. It doesn't complain on the second run of the setup program so there's something inconsistent. A large user base inspires confidence but a bad installation detracts from the perceived quality.